# I can't not run python tex in my document

Tags: pythontex

His code not run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
This is my code.
\begin{pycode}
    a='andrey'
    print('Hi es ',a)
\end{pycode}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? first and foremost, unindent the python code.

Comment: dont print the message...

Comment: What is the error message? You need to be more descriptive about your problem in order for someone to be able to help you. Show the log file.

Comment: latex just print This is my code, and should be This is my code Hi es andrey

Comment: Yes I know what your code produces and what is the expected output. I'm asking you what the error message is. Did you run pythontex.py? Do you even have python installed on your system?

Comment: I have texlive2017 and Anaconda(with python3.6). After run pdflatex(F6) what I have else to do?

Comment: @AndreyVinajera I don't know, but you should add that info to the post. Just write ' I have run F6 and don't know how to continue'. Also that you are using anac.

Comment: You have to (1) remove the indentation from the code; (2) run `pdflatex`, then `pythontex`, then `pdflatex` again. What TeX front-end are you using?